# Glance screen background is not showing

Tags: 8.1-update-1, lumia-denim-update, glance

I set background to the glance screen using **Glance kBackground** app. But from last 2 weeks, it's not showing.

Comment: Recently, Microsoft have released a glance screen update . So as for the update, do note that you have to restart your phone for the changes to be visible.

Comment: What phone are you using?

Comment: @Thomas, Lumia 620

Comment: @vembutech, I'm having the latest version of glance screen and I might restarted many times these two weeks

Comment: Have you enabled battery saver at all?

Comment: @RowlandShaw Nope. I tried reinstalling both the glance setting and glance background. Nothing made sense.

Comment: Have you tried the ever faithful hard reset?

Comment: I did a reinstall using recovery tool for another reason last week. But glance screen issue is still there.